# how to use if else to set var value in linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

How do you use if-else to set var value in linux shell?

I am a starter of linux.  I want to set var value with conditions in shell.  How to do it ?
The code below is php code; I don't know how to write in linux.

```
#!bin/bash
# how to use if else to set var value in linux shell
if($x==1){
    $y="hello"
}
if($x==2){
    $y="world"
}
if($x==3){
    $y="good"
}

echo $y
```

Comment: Don't you think you should start by learning the language before you ask for help? What you posted isn't even close to correct. You seem to be writing PHP, not bash.

Comment: For instance, you don't even know how to assign a variable, regardless of `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if else in bash
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples/

```
#!/bin/bash
count=100
if [ $count -eq 100 ]
then
  echo "Count is 100"
fi
```

to set a var in bash
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html

```
#!/bin/bash          
            STR="Hello World!"
            echo $STR
```